# Parse.com URL Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parse-platform, backend

We're using Parse.com as our backend. We're setting up a service so that any user (who logs in or makes an account) can create an "Event".  This "event" would include a date, location, description, title, etc. I've configured the schema so that this works.

But here's the problem: I need this to be public so that once the user creates the new event, they can share that link to anyone in the world. I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are many ways to generate URLs. If security is not a concern you can give each event a unique identifier and simply pass out URLs with that identifier, like `mydomain.org?event=12345`. If security is an issue you can use crypto libraries to generate random strong tokens.

Comment: @Halcyon Thanks. How would I go about doing this with parse.com, though? I have read through their docs and could not find anything like this.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with their service. Perhaps parse.com does not offer the service that you need.